# Correct usage of comparison containing percentages

Tags: grammaticality, comparison

I'd like to understand whether this sentence sounds natural and is grammatically correct. I'm mostly concerned about the usage of a percentage and the preposition: **X% more of ...** Couldn't find any useful guidelines on this topic.

> Service providers who implemented chat-bots on their websites get 20% more of orders placed on their websites.

Comment: It would be more natural with consistent use of tenses, without the repetition, and without the 'of' – "Service providers who implement chat-bots on their website get 20% more orders placed there."

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more idiomatic version of the same:

> Service providers who implemented chat-bots on their websites get 20% more orders.

There is no requirement to repeat "placed on their websites." as you are already mentioning that the chat-bot is on the website.